# Can I Illustrator Symbols with editable text that does not update all instances?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, symbols

I was wondering if it's possible to create Symbols with editable text elements in Illustrator CS6, i.e. when using form elements in wire framing.

I'm seeking to use live text in symbols but *not* have all symbol instances update should the text in a single symbol change.

Comment: It is possible. Does your text get converted to vectors? I am unsure what the problem is.

Comment: Well, when I edit the text element within the symbol, I change all instances of the symbol, don't I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't include the text elements into the symbol - they will (as you said) be altered on all instances if you change the text on one of them. I often create the symbol with the graphics only and add text to each of the instances.